# Display ASCII characters in rows and columns using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

So, I was reading an article about character sets and decided to write a script to display the ascii characters and their values.
Here is the code I came up with:Actually I got it from an example I saw here on SO.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tbl = $("<table>");
for (var i = 0; i < 128/32; i++) {
   var nextrow =$("<tr>");
  $(tbl).append(nextrow);
  var nextitem = 32*i;
  for(var j = 0; j < 32 && nextitem + j < 128; j++){
    var nextcell = $("<td>");
    $(nextcell).html(nextitem+j + ":" +String.fromCharCode(nextitem + j));
    $(nextrow).append(nextcell);
  } 
}
  $("body").append(tbl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  </body>
```

However, the results are being displayed horizontally(0..31) instead of vertically.
I am wondering how can I make it display vertically...that is, put the first 32 characters in one column, then the next 32 in another column, etc.

And what is more, is there a better way of doing this, without using tables that is?
Thanks.

Comment: "without using tables": I think you are saying that 4 columns of 32 is not intrinsic to the data; you just want to display it that way here. Semantically, it is a sequence of bidirectional (one-to-one) mappings, ordered by the ASCII code. In HTML, you could model this as an ordered list of paired divs (disadv. divs do not imply meaning) or a description list (disadv. this type of list does not imply order and allows many-to-one), or just a table of two columns (all the disadvantages but is more common and simpler). Is what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   var nextcol =$("<div class=\"col\">");
  $("body").append(nextcol);
  var nextitem = 32*i;
  for(var j = 0; j < 32; j++){
    var nextcell = $("<div>");
    $(nextcell).html(nextitem+j + ":" +String.fromCharCode(nextitem + j));
    $(nextcol).append(nextcell);
  } 
}
});
```

```css
.col {
    display: inline-block;
}
.col > div {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  </body>
```

Comment: To display [Control Picture](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) characters (may not display in your browser), replace `nextitem + j` with `utf16CodeUnit` and preceed with `var unicodeCodepoint = nextitem + j;
        /* all of the codepoints are encoded in just one UTF-16 code unit */
        var utf16CodeUnit = unicodeCodepoint > 0x0020 ? unicodeCodepoint : unicodeCodepoint == 0x007f ? 0x2421: unicodeCodepoint + 0x2400;`

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Good job